# filter elasticsearch aggregation by parent bucket key value

Tags: elasticsearch

My index mapping in Elasticsearch is as follows:

```
"mappings":
{
    "properties":{
        "method_id": {
            "type": "long"
        }
        "tree_path": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample documents:

```
{
    "tree_path": "/1/2/3/4",
    "method_id": 4 
}
{
    "tree_path": "/1/2/3",
    "method_id": 3 
}
{
    "tree_path": "/1/2",
    "method_id": 2 
}
```

- method_id refers to the last method in the tree_path.

**My question -**

I need to query Elasticsearch in the following way -

Query input - A list of method_ids.

Query output - **For each** method_id find All documents whose tree_path **contains** this method_id anywhere in the tree_path and perform an aggregation.

I created the following query, but the part of retrieving method_id from parent bucket doesn't work.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms":{
                        "method_id":[
                            2,3
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "filter_method_id_agg":{
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "method_id": [
                        2,3
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "by_method_id_agg":{
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "method_id"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "by_tree_path":{
                            "filter":{
                                "term":{
                                    "tree_path": "_key"
                                }
                            },
                            "aggs":{
                                // MY AGGRIGATION - sum of a numeric field.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would love to get some help here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A text type field can be used as a keyword type field if you set fielddata = true

The path is splitted into parts by the split_path_analyzer. Then the method_id is searched for

Mapping with analyzer

```
PUT /paths
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "split_path_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "split_path_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "split_path_tokenizer": {
          "type": "simple_pattern_split",
          "pattern": "/"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "method_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "tree_path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "splitted": {
            "analyzer": "split_path_analyzer",
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your documents

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"paths","_id":"1"}}
{"tree_path":"/1/2/3/4","method_id":4}
{"index":{"_index":"paths","_id":"2"}}
{"tree_path":"/1/2/3","method_id":3}
{"index":{"_index":"paths","_id":"3"}}
{"tree_path":"/1/2","method_id":2}
```

Aggregation query

```
GET /paths/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tree_path.splitted": [
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_method_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tree_path.splitted",
        "include": ["2", "3"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see how the path was splitted into tokens by the query

```
GET /paths/_termvectors/1?filter_path=term_vectors
{
    "fields": ["tree_path.splitted"],
    "field_statistics": false,
    "positions": false,
    "offsets": false
}
```